# Apache 2.2 WebDav Anonymous access

Tags: apache

I sorta have a HTTP config working for Apache 2.2 that allows WebDav. At least I can use the WinSCP client to attach with the DAV account listed below.

But I also have much older clunkier clients that may only work for anonymous access. And they are not working.

1. Windows 7 (Map drive), it pops up the credentials but does not log in.
2. FalconView (probably only understands anonymous login

Any idea what I am doing wrong here with the anon access? I am a novice at HTTPD.conf

(the environment variable ${EGPL_JobsPath} resolves to a windows path:

E.g. F:\Jobs

```
Alias /jobs ${EGPL_JobsPath}
<IfModule dav_lock_module>
    DavLockDB "${EGPL_JobsPath}"
</IfModule>
<Directory "${EGPL_JobsPath}">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Dav On
    Require valid-user
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all  
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require user me
    </LimitExcept>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName DAV
    AuthUserFile conf/users.passwords
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work, is to turn off all Authentication and leave the webdav folder open to the world. I would still like to hear from people with better ideas:

```
Alias /jobs ${EGPL_JobsPath}
<IfModule dav_lock_module>
    DavLockDB "${EGPL_LibrarianPath}"
</IfModule>
<Directory "${EGPL_JobsPath}">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Dav On
</Directory>
```